# Adding Columns with nested relationships in backpack for laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have 3 models created in backpack for laravel CRUD:

Driver, Municipality and Province.

Driver has  a 'municipality_id' and the relationship function:

```
public function municipality()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Municipality');
}
```

To get the province of the driver i need to  use a relationship function inside Municipality model:

```
public function province()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Province');
}
```

The driver model does **not** contain the province function so i have to to something like

```
$objdriver->municipality->province->name;
```

To get the province name.

Now the problem is that i have to add 2 columns in the table created by artisan that display the municipality name and the province name.

For the municipality it's easy and i did it like this:

```
$this->crud->addColumn('municipality_id', [
        // 1-n relationship
        'label' => "Comune", // Table column heading
        'type' => "select",
        'name' => 'municipality_id', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
        'entity' => 'municipality', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => "name", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => "App\Models\Municipality", // foreign key model
     ]);
```

And it works Fine, but how do i add a column for the Provinces? Since the method is not in the driver model i can't use the same approach.

I already tried using a custom function to fetch what i need from the province table, something like:

```
$this->crud->addColumn('province_id', [
        // run a function on the CRUD model and show its return value
        'name' => "province_id",
        'label' => "Provincia", // Table column heading
        'type' => "model_function",
        'function_name' => 'GetProvinceName', // the method in your Model

     ])
```

where GetProvinceName is:

```
public function GetProvinceName()
{
    return $this->municipality->province->name;
}
```

but that just gives out an error.

Comment: Just use `province.name` as the field name, providing the relationship is set up Backpack will handle it.

Comment: @Joe i don't think i quite understand what you mean by 'field name'. Am i supposed to do something like: `'name' => 'province.name'` in the addColumn method? Because that doesn't make too much sense

Comment: Yes exactly that, I've used that exact method in a Backpack page today. If you're on the driver listing view you would just do `"name" => "municipality.province.name"`

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following code.

```
  $this->crud->addColumn([
    'name' => 'municipality.province.name', // the relationships are handled automatically
    'label' => 'Provincia', // the grid's column heading
    'type' => 'text'
  ]);
```